# Accessing the Mosquitto Broker from a different network

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I have 3 virtual machines VM1, VM2 and VM3. VM1 and VM2 are in the same network. My Mosquitto Broker is running in a docker Container on VM2. The docker container is connected to the Host network (so it has the same IP as the VM2). the configuration file of the broker is:

```
port 1883
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

allow_anonymous true
```

[image]
I can access the broker on VM2 from a container on VM1 (VM1 and VM2 are in the same network). Also I can `ping` VM2 from VM3 (VM3 and VM2 not the on same network) but I cannot access the broker on VM2 from VM3 or via `mqtt-explorer`.

any hint?! where could the error be? where should I search?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could be an issue with the firewall configuration, perhaps on one of the hosts, or the network itself. Could be a routing issue. You should trace this with tcpdump at each point along the connection to see where it drops.

Answer (score 0):

`port 1883` will not change the default listener which is bound to `localhost` only for security reasons.

You should remove `port 1883` and replace it with `listener 1883`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I changed it and restarted the docker container with the new configuration but unfortunately it is still not working (I can't access the broker from outside VM3). Any other Suggestions please ? many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Edit the question to show the logs from the broker

Comment: Also since this is all in VMs you should be able to attach a tool like wireshark to see all the network traffic